# xlsxwriter formulas SLOPE, INTERCEPT do not work

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Does anyone know why? I write these formulas with `write_formula`:

```
slopeFormula = "=SLOPE(H96:H100;E96:E100)"
ws.write_formula("D105", slopeFormula)
interceptFormula = "=INTERCEPT(H96:H100;E96:E100)"
ws.write_formula("D106", interceptFormula)
```

I have tried these formulas directly in Excel and worked fine. But when I intert them through Python, the workbook gets unreadable:

```
Excel could not open file.xlsx because some content is unreadable. Do you want to open and repair this workbook?
```

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't with the formulae but with the separator used in the formulae.

From the `write_formula()` [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-formula):

> Also, formulas must be written with the US style separator/range operator which is a comma (not semi-colon). Therefore a formula with multiple values should be written as follows:

```
worksheet.write_formula('A1', '=SUM(1, 2, 3)')  # OK
worksheet.write_formula('A2', '=SUM(1; 2; 3)')  # NO. Error on load.
```

Comment: I feel dumbass. Thank you!